# setting culture in powershell script, sum

Tags: powershell, culture

I'm loading some CSV data in a powershell script and doing a group and sum on a field. It as such work fine but the sum is not calculated correcty, as it uses wrong culture setting, for some reason. My data use , as separator and not .

I have tried to set the culture, but does not work.

Set-Culture -CultureInfo da-DK;

what can i Do?

Comment: Please show us some of the input data as formatted text in your question

Answer (score 0):

To set a Culture for only the scope of a script use `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture=Get-Culture -Name da-DK`
(it starts having effect only for the line after it has been called)

But if you are importing from a CSV from a specific Culture then you should use `Import-Csv` with `-UseCulture` after setting the culture

(obviously `da-DK` would change depending on the culture involved)

Answer (score 0):

A sum would be a integer maths sum. When you import from a csv, it comes in as text. So that might be your problem. rather than the delimiter. (CSV defaults to ',' comma delimiter. but you can change it during the import. for example

***import-csv -delimiter '.' file.csv***

What it sounds like you need to do though, is change the column you want to a integer (number). As you do not paste your CSV format, here is a example

Name,Age

dave,21

steve,45

now import it, and convert the age column to a number:

***$CSVData = import-csv myfile.csv | select Name,@{l='Age';e={[int]$_.Age}}***

Now, the variable $CSVData will have the age column as a number, and this be sortable and able to do maths on etc.